# Upload local file contents without page refresh

Tags: ajax, spring-mvc, file-upload, javascript

I have a page in my web flow where I want to upload a file without refreshing the page.  I tried using an Ajax call for that, but failed. I couldn't figure out how to send the data in the uploaded file to the server side/back end for further processing. I'm using the Spring MVC framework and I don't want to use PHP.

Can anyone suggest a solution or some sample code with which I can get my job done? I am very new to JavaScript.

One more thing is i have to get back to the same page after going to server side to process uploaded file and return to same page with a string from server side.all this happen without refreshing the current page

Any suggestion would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Google "HTML5 File API" -> http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/dndfiles/

Comment: Just use an ajax uploader like http://valums.com/ajax-upload/ or whatnot and process the upload as an usual multipart form submit in your spring framework.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you've already gotten your form built and server-side controller set up to handle the upload, this little snippet should get you on your way to AJAX-y refresh-less file uploading glory!

```
//create a new FormData reference
//(note: you could use getElementById or querySelector)
var myForm = document.forms.myUploadForm; 
var fd = new FormData(myForm);

//create and open an XHR
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open("POST","http://www.example.url/the/path/to/your/upload/controller");

//set up event listeners (optional)
xhr.onreadystatechange = monitorStatusFunction;
xhr.onprogress = updateProgressBarFunction;

//send the form (w/ no page refresh!)
xhr.send(fd);
```

Comment: but if i do like this this it will become a normal post method....        my problem is that i should get back to the same page with the data in the file after some manipulation on the server side...their i becoming hopeless...pls help me

Comment: Did you actually try it? I use this snippet all the time, and it makes the browser upload the file(s) in the form and does not refresh the page, so it's definitely an AJAX POST, not a "normal" one. What exactly do you want to happen with the file after you process it on the server? You want to overwrite the original file on the client's disk? Do you want to download it as a new file? Do you want to do more processing on the client side? Do you want to render it in the page somewhere? Do you just want to send a confirmation message? Sorry, I guess I don't quite understand what you need to do...

Comment: sry for confusing you......what i actually want is,i have a page where i will ask the client to upload a file then i have to read the content of the file on the server side process it and return a string to the same page depending upon the content of the file.this all should happen without refreshing the page

Comment: I'm writing a webservice using Spring MVC that does exactly that: upload a file, manipulate its contents on the server, and send back a string to the client's page without refreshing it. This code that I've posted here is almost exactly the code I run on the client side to achieve this. I don't understand how/why it's not what you want...  Again, have you actually tried using it? Note: If you're calling this  code when the user presses a submit button on the form, you'll need to explicitly prevent the default submit button behavior. Otherwise, it should work fine. It does for me!

Comment: I'm happy to help you out more, btw - I wish I'd had more help when I was getting started doing this! But it's probably best not to keep having the conversation in the comments here - feel free to shoot me an email!

Answer (score 0):

I Struggled for lot many days and at last i figured out a solution which may not be the best solution but i am posting it here so that anyone like me can get help from this..

To meet all my requirements

I opened a jsp page as a popup from my jsp page and from that page i landed on my controller and done with my work on the server side and returned a string depending upon the content of the file uploaded to the same popup page and from the popup i transfered that string to my parent page.

Hence my work is done without refreshing the page...
Steps to do this
1.open a popup as follow

> window.open('//url of jsp page to open','//somename','//properties of popup page');

2.land on your controller from the popup and return to the same jsp page with a string i want from the jsp page.
3.pass that string to the parent page as follow.

> window.open.urparentjspfuntion(valuefromcontroller);

4.in parent page define a function to do what ever you want.....

I hope this solution may help so of those like me...